# Exporting a global map from google earth engine

Tags: export, global, google-earth-engine

How does one export a global map from Google Earth Engine. I tried setting the bounding box to the following coordinates -180, -90, 180, 90 and what I get is a single column of data. I need these data at a resolution of 1km and 5 km. If this is not possible, what is a work around?

Thanks,
Rekha

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer here. It involved creating a non-geodesic polygon as described in this link below.
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/427210/how-do-i-download-global-hansen-global-forest-change-data-from-gee

Comment: Please spell out the answer! Links tend to rot, even on StackExchange.